# Can a partial view be used to do Ajax item updates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a table built from a list of defect codes.

Can part of each row load a sub-table item complete with submit buttons?

Sample table:

```
<table><tr>
<th>Code</th><th>Description</th>
<th>Impact to your customers</th>
<th>Impact to your associates</th>
<th>Save</th>
<th>Save Errors</th></tr>
```

Where the first 2 columns are populated from the lookup table, and the next 3 columns are a form so the user can set the values or update them from previous values.

Can I somehow have 3 `TD` items per row an individual Ajax form with the codeId embedded as a hidden value? What would my strongly typed view(s) inherit? the outer layer would inherit `IEnumerable<DefectDTO>`, and the partial views would inherit the `AssessmentDTO` type?

Here's the actual table I'm trying to get to function:

```
<table>
    <tr>

        <th>
            Code
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Document
        </th>
        <th>
            Customer Contact Required for Resolution
        </th>
        <th>
            AssociateSeverity
        </th>
        <th>
            ShareholderSeverity
        </th>
        <th>
            CustomerSeverity
        </th>
        <th>
            RegulatorySeverity
        </th>
        <th>
            RootCause
        </th>
        <th>
            Investor Requirements*
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model.DefectCodes) { %>

    <tr>
        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new AjaxOptions() ))
           {%>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Code)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Description)%>
        </td>
        <%  Html.RenderPartial("Create",null, ViewData); %><!-- This is where the form is -->
        <% } %>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you add more details, like the models you are using? as far as i understand you need a partial form inside your table, with two diferent models, one to display the first two columns and the other one for the forms, but why you have two buttons foreach row(Save and Save Errors)?

Comment: There would be only 1 button, save. the last column would be the validation summary/validation errors. I can add more details back at work tomorrow also if this doesn't show enough of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.DefectCodes) { %>

    <tr>
        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new AjaxOptions() ))
           {%>

        <!--should be easy like this!--><!--ur codeid here-->
        <%=Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.codeid)%> 

        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Code)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Description)%>
        </td>
        <%  Html.RenderPartial("Create",null, ViewData); %><!-- This is where the form is -->
        <% } %>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
```

its just solves ur hidden value! problem..

u dont need to put it into a `TD` cause u want it to be hidden so it will still get the value for u but will not be shown in form or in table or in view.. that way u can keep 3 `TD` and get more value than the shown on form.